# Inserting data to the room database from the adapter class crashes the app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I've been trying to insert data to the room database from the adapter class when an onclicklistener event happens. But everytime I do that my app crashes without any error message in the logcat. The only thing that happens in the event is that the database instance gets created and as soon as that happens the app crashes.

My item class :

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName="item")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "path")
    val path: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val itemName: String,
)
```

My DAO :

```kotlin
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    //suspend is not needed in newer versions of kotlin
    fun insert(item: Item)

}
```

My ItemRoomDatabase.kt :

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ItemRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ItemRoomDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): ItemRoomDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    ItemRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "item_database"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Starred application code :

```kotlin
class StarredApplication : Application() {
    val database: ItemRoomDatabase by lazy { ItemRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this) }

}
```

And here's my InventoryViewModel.kt :

```kotlin
class InventoryViewModel(private val itemDao: ItemDao) : ViewModel()  {

    private fun insertItem(item: Item) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            itemDao.insert(item)
        }
    }


    fun isEntryValid(path: String, name: String): Boolean {
        if (path.isBlank() || name.isBlank()) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun getNewItemEntry(path: String, name: String): Item {
        return Item(
            path = path,
            itemName = name,
        )
    }

    fun addNewItem(path: String, name: String) {
        val newItem = getNewItemEntry(path, name)
        insertItem(newItem)
    }
}

class InventoryViewModelFactory(private val itemDao: ItemDao) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(InventoryViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return InventoryViewModel(itemDao) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

So in my fragment (PdfContainerFragment.kt) I create a viewModel instance of the inventory view model and pass it to the adapter class.

```kotlin
    private val viewModel: InventoryViewModel by activityViewModels {
        InventoryViewModelFactory(
            (activity?.application as StarredApplication).database.itemDao()
        )
    }
```

So in my adapter class i try to insert data to the room database but the app crashes as soon as i click on the event.

// Inside onBindViewHolder

```kotlin
     holder.star.setOnClickListener{

            with(model){
                setPath(paths)
            }

            var pdfName = holder.textView.text.toString()
            Log.d("PathPdfContainerAdapter", paths)
            Log.d("pdfNamePdfAdapter", pdfName)

            addNewItem( paths, pdfName)
            holder.star.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_fill)
        }

// Outside onViewBinding

    private fun isEntryValid(path: String, pdfName: String): Boolean {
        return roomViewModel.isEntryValid(
            path,
            pdfName,
        )
    }

    private fun addNewItem( path: String, name: String) {
        if(isEntryValid(path, name)) {
            roomViewModel.addNewItem(
                path,
                name,
            )
        }
    }
```

I am new to app development so please dumb it down for me to understand.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Hi. We can't help you with just the code of the app.
use logcat to catch the error and paste it in the question. that will help a lot.
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: So while normally executing my app, it crashes without any log in the logcat but I just learned a bit of using debugger today and found this error
`Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`

Answer (score 1):

So what was happening was that my app crashes without any message on the logcat so I tried using debugger and found an exception of

`Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`

So while building my database I applied my databaseBuilder to allowMainThreadQueries. This isn't a perfect solution but it works for now.

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ItemRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ItemRoomDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): ItemRoomDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    ItemRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "item_database"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```